# Jquery Pop Up with Radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, popup

hi I am trying to write a jquery code which on click displays a popwindow and has radio buttons in it.
Here is my jquery code:

```
$("#myPopup").ready(function() {

var popUpList = $('<div><input type="radio">A<br><input type="radio">B<br>
<input type="radio">C</div>');

showPopUpButton.click(myFunction() {
    popUpList.dialog();
 });
});
```

Here is the respective popup call code:

```
<li class="header_navigation_list">
    <div data-role="main" class="header_navigation_link">
         <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
          <button id ="showPopUpButton" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
          <p>This is a simple popup.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span>|</span>
</li>
```

The jquery code on .js page throws error as " Multiple markers at this line (FunctionExpressionHeaderName expected) ". Seems I am not properly calling function in jquery. Can someone please advice on this. TIA

Comment: One error, probably not immediately related to the message you're getting, is that you need `name` and `value` attributes on the radiobuttons - the `name` needs to be the same for all buttons in the group, the `value` is what will be returned when the form is submitted.

Comment: ok could you please give a one line example of name and value pair in radio button. Also just now I am able to select all values in radio button, i just want to select a single value at a time. Further after selecting a value in radio button i need to call a window.open function.

Comment: Search for "html radio button syntax" you will find lots of examples

Comment: tried it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the carriage return in your `popUpList` var, use the `#showPopUpButton` jquery object with `$.on()`, and remove the `onclick` handler in your HTML.

```js
$("#myPopup").ready(function() {
  var popUpList = $(
    '<div><input type="radio">A<br><input type="radio">B<br><input type="radio">C</div>'
  );

  $('#showPopUpButton').on('click',function() {
    popUpList.dialog();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<li class="header_navigation_list">
  <div data-role="main" class="header_navigation_link">
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
      <button id="showPopUpButton">Click me</button>
      <p>This is a simple popup.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>|</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Just now I am able to select all values in radio button, i just want to select a single value at a time. Further after selecting a value in radio button i need to call a window.open function.

Comment: @RJ_Programmer you're welcome. That is beyond the scope of your original question. Try it yourself, and if you can't figure it out, post another question.

Comment: @RJ_Programmer awesome, you're welcome. be sure to accept an answer once you feel the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Code which worked:

```
 $("#myPopup").ready(function() {
   var popUpList = $(
    '<div><input type="radio" name="popup_w" value="1">1<br><input type="radio" name="popup_w" value="2">2<br><input type="radio" name="popup_w" value="3">3</div>'
  );

  $('#showPopUpButton').on('click',function() {
    popUpList.dialog();
  });
});
```

JSP CODE:

```
                <li class="header_navigation_list">
           <div data-role="main" class="header_navigation_link">
         <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>
            <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
                <button id="showPopUpButton"> To change the window size, click here</button>
            <!--    <p>This is a simple popup.</p>  -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <span>|</span>
        </li>
```